# How to add a new line in text field of dropdown in semantic-ui react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Here is the render function

```
render(){
    const { members, user } = this.props;
    let memberOptions = [];
    members.forEach((member, i) => {
      memberOptions.push({
        key: i,
        text: member.user.name,
        value: member.user.id,
        image: { avatar: true, src: member.user.gravatar },
      });
    });
    return (
      <Dropdown placeholder='Select User' fluid selection options={memberOptions} />
    )
  }
```

This will render perfectly. But I also want to add one more text(say email) in this **text field in a new line**. So that dropdown items show  similar to this : https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/list#list-example-relaxed

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i don't understant you want to add "email" in your  memberOptions ?

Comment: yes, So that it should look like this : https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/list#list-example-relaxed

Comment: Add mail: « data » in the memberOption.pueg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Akhila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5946125/akhila-hegde), I would recommend that you use the `content` prop instead of the `text` prop for your `Dropdown.Item` that you are rendering from your `memberOptions` array. The `text` prop specifically expects a string. The `content` prop will accept anything, including other React components or nodes. So instead of returning `text` as a string, you could do something like this for content, maybe as a separate class method on your component:

```
const renderItemContent = (member) => {
  const {
    email,
    name,
  } = member.user;

  const emailStyle = {
    color    : '#333',
    fontSize : '.875em',
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      {name}
      {email &&
        <div style={emailStyle}>{email}</div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Then set `content: this.renderItemContent(member)` on your memberOptionsArray.

Comment: Unfortunately the functionality has been changed. But this works. thank you.